# Node transform stream: append string to end

Tags: node.js, stream

How do I create a transform stream, where the only change it will effect, is appending a string to the *end* of a the incoming readable stream.

For example, let's say **input.txt** contains `abcdef`.

```
fs.createReadStream('input.txt', {encoding: 'utf8'})
    .pipe(appendTransform)
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output.txt', {encoding: 'utf8'}));
```

What can I use for `appendTransform`, such that **output.txt** contains `abcdefghi`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a transform stream:

```
var Transform = require('stream').Transform;

var appendTransform = new Transform({
    transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        callback(null, chunk);
    },
    flush(callback) {
        this.push('ghi');
        callback();
    }
});
```